# Android - ChromeOS - BottomSheetDialogFragment is not working on ChromeOS full screen

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, androidappsonchromeos

I'm extending `BottomSheetDialogFragment`for show a bottom menu on the application. This is the layout used for the view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:contentPaddingBottom="16dp"
        app:contentPaddingTop="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="menu 1"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1px"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:contentPaddingBottom="16dp"
        app:contentPaddingTop="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="menu 2"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My issue is when the application runs on full screen on the ChromeOS, the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is not draw correctly.

[App on full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOgi3.png)

When the application runs on window mode the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` draws correctly.

[App on Window Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEJMd.png)

When i toggle the application on full screen with another app, the application shows correctly

[App on full screen - after toggle the application with keep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTbVZ.png)

Google Chrome OS version - 69.0.3497.95 (stable version)

Comment: Hi! Did you find the solution?. Myself also have the same problem.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? Having the same problem..

Comment: This been fixed by google on the ChromeOS newest stable versions